# dig (DNS Lookup) specify DNS server on Windows

Tags: powershell, dns, dig

In Linux, I would use `dig` to specify a DNS server of 127.0.0.1 with the following command:

```
dig google.com @127.0.0.1
```

I installed Bind tools for windows (`choco install bind-toolsonly`). How can I run that same command? I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\jhilden> dig google.com @127.0.0.1
At line:1 char:21
+ dig google.com @127.0.0.1
+                     ~
Missing property name after reference operator.
At line:1 char:16
+ dig google.com @127.0.0.1
+                ~~~~
The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an
expression. '@127' can be used only as an argument to a command. To
reference variables in an expression use '$127'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingPropertyName
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like the error message says: the `@` has a [special meaning](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) in PowerShell. Escape the character

```
dig google.com `@127.0.0.1
```

or put the argument in quotes

```
dig google.com "@127.0.0.1"
```

Answer (score 74):

I know this answer doesn't use Bind tools, as you inferred in your question. That said, however, PowerShell comes with the `Resolve-DnsName` to perform this task. I believe that the following command will do what you are after

```
Resolve-DnsName -Name google.com -Server 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: @r590 Upon investigation, it appears that `Resolve-DnsName` was added in PowerShell 3.0, so is only available on Windows 8+ / Windows Server 2012+_

Comment: note that WMF 5.1 (which includes PowerShell 5.1) has been back-ported to Windows 7 SP1 - so anything W7SP1, Server 2008R2SP1 or later should be able to run a full set of PowerShell commands.

Comment: This does not support a `port`. Any other possibilities?

Comment: [Reference doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/resolve-dnsname?view=windowsserver2019-ps)

Answer (score -3):

I think your parameters are backwards.  Server should come first.

Comment: Nope. Argument order doen't matter here.